# Using string from public static void in private bool C#

Tags: c#, mysql

So I am trying to validate a string I received from a MySQL database but for some reason cannot access. I am sure this is a dumb question but can anyone help me out? I feel like it might be related to the public vs private and the static but after playing around with every combination I can think of to pass through the variables, it still keeps giving me errors. Any ideas?

```
string failReason = "";
int valid = 0;

public static void getNewRow()
    {

        try
        {
            string getNewRow = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE valid IS NULL";

            DbConnection mysqlDB = new DbConnection();

            MySqlCommand mysqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(getNewRow, mysqlDB.GetLocalMySQLConnection());

            MySqlDataReader reader = mysqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {


                    int id = reader.GetInt32("id");
                    string accountID = reader.GetString("accountID");
                    string appDate = reader.GetString("appDate");
                    string appTime = reader.GetString("apptime");
                    string patientName = reader.GetString("patientName");
                    string appPhone = reader.GetString("appPhone");
                    string appPhone2 = reader.GetString("appPhone2");
                    string smsPhone = reader.GetString("smsPhone");
                    string special = reader.GetString("special");
                    string email = reader.GetString("email");
                    string provider = reader.GetString("provider");
                    string location = reader.GetString("location");
                    string other = reader.GetString("other");



                    Console.WriteLine("ID: " + id);
                    Console.WriteLine("AccountID: " + accountID);
                    Console.WriteLine("Appointment Date: " + appDate);
                    Console.WriteLine("Appointment Time: " + appTime);
                    Console.WriteLine("Patient Name: " + patientName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Phone 1: " + appPhone);
                    Console.WriteLine("Phone 2: " + appPhone2);
                    Console.WriteLine("SMS Phone: " + smsPhone);
                    Console.WriteLine("Special: " + special);
                    Console.WriteLine("Email: " + email);
                    Console.WriteLine("Provider: " + provider);
                    Console.WriteLine("Location: " + location);
                    Console.WriteLine("Other: " + other);







            }




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }

    private bool validName()
    {
        if (patientName.Length < 20)
        {
            failReason = "Bad Name";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

private bool validName()
    {
        if (patientName.Length < 20)
        {
            failReason = "Bad Name";
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you point out the specific error and location that is the problem?

Comment: Is "private bool validName()" twice or is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry, only one private bool validName()

Comment: Error is patientName does not exist in current context in private bool validName()

Comment: `giving me errors` we aren't psychic. We don't have your program (DON'T pastebin the entire thing though!). Post the *exact* errors and indicate exactly where they are happening. Have you googled the errors to understand what they are and why they are happening? Any effort so far to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patientName` exists only within the scope of `getNewRow`. You need to make that a class-scoped variable (like you did with `failReason` if you want to use them anywhere outside of `getNewRow`. You can also pass them as parameters, but I don't see that your methods have parameters to begin with.

Comment: I had tried making them global class-scoped but then get the error in getRow() that an object reference is required for non-static field, method, or property

Comment: @trehm07 Show your code with that change made. That's great you've included an actual error message, but you still need to indicate *where* it's happening. We aren't psychic.

Answer (score 0):

```
string patientName = reader.GetString("patientName");
```

is local to 
    public static void getNewRow()

make it as such:

```
static string failReason = "";
static int valid = 0;
static string patientName = string.Empty;

public static void getNewRow()
{

    try
    {
        string getNewRow = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE valid IS NULL";

        DbConnection mysqlDB = new DbConnection();

        MySqlCommand mysqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(getNewRow, mysqlDB.GetLocalMySQLConnection());

        MySqlDataReader reader = mysqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {


                int id = reader.GetInt32("id");
                string accountID = reader.GetString("accountID");
                string appDate = reader.GetString("appDate");
                string appTime = reader.GetString("apptime");
                patientName = reader.GetString("patientName");
                string appPhone = reader.GetString("appPhone");
                string appPhone2 = reader.GetString("appPhone2");
                string smsPhone = reader.GetString("smsPhone");
                string special = reader.GetString("special");
                string email = reader.GetString("email");
                string provider = reader.GetString("provider");
                string location = reader.GetString("location");
                string other = reader.GetString("other");



                Console.WriteLine("ID: " + id);
                Console.WriteLine("AccountID: " + accountID);
                Console.WriteLine("Appointment Date: " + appDate);
                Console.WriteLine("Appointment Time: " + appTime);
                Console.WriteLine("Patient Name: " + patientName);
                Console.WriteLine("Phone 1: " + appPhone);
                Console.WriteLine("Phone 2: " + appPhone2);
                Console.WriteLine("SMS Phone: " + smsPhone);
                Console.WriteLine("Special: " + special);
                Console.WriteLine("Email: " + email);
                Console.WriteLine("Provider: " + provider);
                Console.WriteLine("Location: " + location);
                Console.WriteLine("Other: " + other);







        }




    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
    }
}

private static bool validName()
{
    if (patientName.Length < 20)
    {
        failReason = "Bad Name";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

private static bool validName()
{
    if (patientName.Length < 20)
    {
        failReason = "Bad Name";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should decide to make all your methods static or not. You cannot call a non static method from a static method.

Comment: That's not the error OP is getting. And while this is a true statement, I don't see anywhere in the code where OP is doing that. -1